# ASP.NET Core displays the last item of information

Tags: asp.net-core

Sorry, I'm a newbie, and I'd like to ask if there's a way to show only the last piece of information.

```
   @{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@item.Ax</li>       
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display the latest item of the collection:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.LastOrDefault().Ax)
```

The `LastOrDefault()` allows to check if the sequence contains no elements and returns the default value in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to[Enumerable.Last Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#overloads)

Try:

```
@{var last = Model.Last();}
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => last.Ax)
```

Comment: Your way works, thank you very much, but the other answer is earlier, so I'm very sorry I couldn't give you a reward.

Comment: It's ok, glad my answer was useful.